# How to ignore .htaccess file from a parent directory?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using rewrite rules for nice URL's on my websites, the problem is, that I'm supposed to upload a new website and keep an already existing e-shop running. The e-shop is in it's own folder called "shop" in the "/www" directory on the server.

But now my .htaccess file is messing with the e-shop, although it's in the parent directory, how should I block it's effects in the "/shop" dir?

Here's the code:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/?$ shop/ [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1&detail2=$2&detail3=$3&detail4=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1&detail2=$2&detail3=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1&detail2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks for any help, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this above all of your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop
```

Then add a .htaccess file to the /shop directory with *just* this in it.

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

Comment: Will try, what exactly will it do?

Comment: It tells the rewrite engine to only apply the rules if this condition is met.

Comment: Well, works fine for the /shop folder, but could it be modifided, so /shop/admin would also work?

Comment: Well, what I get when I type /shop/admin is /shop/admin/?detail1=shop&detail2=admin =/

Comment: OK, I made another edit and I learned something new :)  Note that I reverted the RewriteCond to the original state I suggested.